# How to calculate the area of a circle ( given: origin, radius ) on a sphere ( Earth )?

Tags: geometry, spherical-geometry

I know that the Earth isn't a sphere, not even an ellipsoid, but for my measurements, its an acceptable approximation.
Assuming I have a coordinate(lat,lon) and a distance( e.g.: 1000km ), what is the surface area on the earth with that distance radius?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a small amplification of the answer by Ross Millikan. Use the same notation as the article he linked to.  I take it that your $1000$ km is the surface of the Earth distance from the center $C$ of your circle to the furthest points $P$ from the center. In the picture linked to, $C$ is the top of the sphere, and $P$ is any point on outer edge of the bottom of the cap.

Assume that this surface of the Earth distance is $d$, and that is is $\le$ $1/4$ of the circumference of the Earth (that's not necessary, but it makes visualization easier).  Let the radius of the Earth be $r$.

Then the angle $\theta$ subtended by the arc $CP$ at the centre of the Earth is given by
$$\theta=\frac{d}{r}.\tag{$\ast$}$$
The "$h$" in the [linked picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap#/media/File:Spherical_cap_diagram.tiff) is given by 
$h=r-r\cos\theta$. The surface area is $2\pi rh$, which is
$$2\pi r^2(1-\cos\theta).\tag{$\ast\ast$}$$ 
Compute $\theta$ using $(\ast)$, and then use $(\ast\ast)$ to find the surface area.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I was missing the (*) equation.

Comment: Actually this answer is incorrect. _θ_ = (_d_ / _r_), in radians, or _θ_ = (_d_ * 360 / (2 _πr_)), in degrees.

Comment: Unless, of course, you are speaking in [turns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turn_(geometry)) ;)

Comment: @HansBrende: Thank you. I will look at it again, tomorrow perhaps.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I thought it might be reasonable to let you know that your answer is mentioned in [this post on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22697/best-approach-for-fixing-a-mistake-when-your-edits-are-rejected). (It seems that the OP asks both about a general issue and about this particular instance.)

Comment: @HansBrende: Thank you for spotting the incorrect $\theta$. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

You could look at [Spherical Cap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap) for the formula.  If you treat the earth as a sphere, the  coordinates of the center do not matter, just the radius and the radius of the earth.

Comment: Thx for the reply, if there would be a distributed solution option I would give the half for u, but since Andrés answer was more detailed...